# How to call a function in a different module in Python and not repeating the function

Tags: python, mysql, function, module

I have defined a function in a different page in Python like so:

```
def getData():
    user=input('Enter Name')
    if user=='Irfan':
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', database='sample_data')
        df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from sample_data.sample_data3', mydb)
    else:
        if user=='Usman':
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', database='')
            df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from sample_data.sample_data1', mydb)

    return df
```

However, because that function is called in many other files in the project, it is asking me over and over again at runtime to enter the user name.

How can I input the user name *once* and then use that cached value to get the required database without having to enter the user name multiple times?

(Sorry for asking in layman's terms; I am a beginner.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the credentials global..

```
user=input('Enter Name')

def getData():
global user
if user=='Irfan':
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', database='sample_data')
    df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from sample_data.sample_data3', mydb)
else:
    if user=='Usman':
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', database='')
        df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from sample_data.sample_data1', mydb)

return df
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
user = ''
def getData():
    if len(user) == 0:
        user=input('Enter Name')
    
    if user=='Irfan':
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', database='sample_data')
        df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from sample_data.sample_data3', mydb)
    else:
        if user=='Usman':
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', database='')
            df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from sample_data.sample_data1', mydb)

    return df
```

By putting the user variable outside of the function it becomes a global variable. Inside you test, if the user variable is already filled or not

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user input once and pass the name as a parameter to your function, like as follows:

```
user = input('Enter name')
def getData(user):
    ##your code
```